# Connect multiple BW systems to one R/3 system

Tags: sap-erp, sap-bw, sap-r3

Is it possible to connect multiple BW systems to one single R/3 system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. 
In each BW System, just setup the R/3 System in question as Source System - for Data Extraction.
Check ["Creating a Source System" in SAP Library](https://help.sap.com/viewer/107a6e8a38b74ede94c833ca3b7b6f51/1.0.3/en-US/f3a10a63626b4674a7b00eb86f75ff79.html) for more details on how to create a Source System configuration.